# Fetching the value from properties file in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a properties file with many key value pairs in it.
I want to fetch the values present in this properties file inside a java script code.How can I do this?

Comment: This question requires more context and explanation to be answerable.

Comment: javascript is one word btw

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple way for iterating in key value pair

1. for IN loop

   for (var key in validation_messages) {

   ```
   if (!validation_messages.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

   var obj = validation_messages[key];
   for (var prop in obj) {
       // skip loop if the property is from prototype
       if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

       // your code
       console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
   }
   ```

   }
2. Map 
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map